# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection :FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation)

Tags: firebase, react-native, warnings

I am working on a react native project using Firebase, and when I try to signup in my application I get this error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 50): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation). FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).

here is my code:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { signUp } from "../firebase";

export default function LoginScreen() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState()
  const [password, setPassword] = useState()
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();

  async function handleSignup() {
    await signUp(emailRef.value, passwordRef.value);
  }

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding">
      <Text style={styles.head}>ParkingApp</Text>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          ref={emailRef}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          ref={passwordRef}
          secureTextEntry
          style={styles.input}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
         /*onPress={{} =>}*/
         style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => handleSignup()}
         style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Register</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}
```

and my firebase file:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
export function signUp(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
}
```

I tried to signup but I get this message:
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 50): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation). FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).